# Implement glossary list

Tags: glossaries

I am trying to make two glossary lists, one with acronyms and one with abbreviation. I have followed the guide on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary but replaced *include{}* with *input{}*. In Texstudio I get the error message *"could not start the command: pdflatex.exe.."*. In Texworks it runs without error message but does not display the list.

The setup
In preamble:

```
\usepackage[acronym,xindy]{glossaries} % nomain, 
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\input{Acronyms.tex}
```

In Acronyms.tex

```
\newacronym{pmw}{PMW}{Passive microwave imager}
\newglossaryentry{qobs}{name = $Q_{obs,t}$ , description = Observed discharge}
```

In master document

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[title=Acronyms]
```

In tex document I refer to the abbreviation like

```
\gls{pmw}
```

Is there an easier way to make an abbreviation or acronym list?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Instead of `\include{Acronyms}` add some entries of this file. Especially somewhere in your code must `gpcc` exist.

Comment: Also don't use `include` to input the file containing your definitions. See [Why shouldn't I use \include to include my glossary definitions?](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#include)

Comment: Nicola: I replaced \include with \input and my document now runs with TexWorks but is not displaying the list (abbreviation are used in documents used to compile). In TexStudio I get the error message "Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Document".tex"up.

Comment: Did you run `makeglossaries` after `pdflatex`?

Comment: The following might help: [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/how-to-makeglossaries-with-texworks) and [MiKTeX and Perl scripts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796/miktex-and-perl-scripts-and-one-python-script)

Comment: makeglossaries are displayed after pdflatex under commands if thats what you mean. I have re-installed MikTex and TexStudio and checked the path in commands is in allignment with http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION0. I have tried to roll back the changes I have made in order to implement glossaries and I have tried to run another tex document.

Comment: I have followed the guide on how to run makeglossaries with TexWorks but I still just get a blank page as I did before following the guide.