# Acronyms list in TexStudio

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am writing few acronyms in my text and I don't want to cross reference them. But just want to have their list printed in the pdf (`pdfLatex`) output  .

I tried with `\acro` and `[acronym]{glossaries}` packages but didn't get an acronyms list. I just got the text *"NY and LA are in US."*

Suggestion please?

Here is a compilable example:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,   % Schriftgröße
paper=a4    
%......
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\begin{document}

\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{us}{US}{United States}

 \section{A}
 NY and LA are in US. 

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glossaries` package (and its extension `glossaries-extra`) provides commands to index and reference terms or abbreviations. This is done by first defining the entries and then using markup commands like `\gls` within the document.

Here's the modified MWE (thank you for providing one!)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}

\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{us}{US}{United States}

\begin{document}

 \section{A}
 \gls{ny} and \gls{la} are in \gls{us}. 

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

 \end{document}
```

In order to make the glossary (list of abbreviations) appear. You need the following build sequence:

1. `pdflatex`
2. `makeglossaries` (a Perl script that automatically runs `makeindex` or `xindy` according to the document settings)
3. `pdflatex`

The second step sometimes causes confusion, so there's an `automake` package option, which will use TeX's shell escape to automatically run `makeindex` or `xindy` for you.

If those steps are successful, the above produces:

[image: New York (NY) and Los Angeles (LA) are in United States (US).]

on the first page and

[image: image of list of abbreviations]

on the last page.

Note I've [moved the `\newacronym` definitions to the preamble](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs). If you want them in the document use the following instead:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}

\usepackage[acronym,automake,docdef=restricted]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

% set the "short" style:
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}

\begin{document}
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{us}{US}{United States}


 \section{A}
 \gls{ny} and \gls{la} are in \gls{us}. 

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

 \end{document}
```

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}

\usepackage[abbreviations,automake,docdef=restricted]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

% set the "short" style:
\setabbreviationstyle{short}

\begin{document}
\newabbreviation{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newabbreviation{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newabbreviation{us}{US}{United States}


 \section{A}
 \gls{ny} and \gls{la} are in \gls{us}. 

\printabbreviations
\end{document}
```

Note that only those entries that have been explicitly marked with commands like `\gls` are added to the list.

If you get the error message:

> ```
> LaTeX Error: Unknown option `automake' for package `glossaries'.
> ```

then your version of `glossaries` is too old. If you don't get this message and you are using `automake` but your list of abbreviations is still missing, check the log file for lines starting with `runsystem`. If it has `disabled` at the end of the line then the shell escape has been disabled, in which case you'll need to find a way to run `makeindex` or `makeglossaries`. Related resources:

- [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309233/what-can-interfere-with-glossaries-to-prevent-printing)
- [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152)
- [Glossaries, Nomenclature, Lists of Symbols and Acronyms](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms)

If you're not interested in the indexing and referencing commands provided by `glossaries` (such as `\gls`), then you don't actually need `glossaries`. For example:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}

\newenvironment{abbrevlist}
{%
  \chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
  \newcommand\entry[2]{\item[##1] ##2}%
  \begin{description}%
}
{\end{description}}

\begin{document}


 \section{A}
 NY and LA are in US.

\begin{abbrevlist}
\entry{LA}{Los Angeles}
\entry{NY}{New York}
\entry{US}{United States}
\end{abbrevlist}

\end{document}
```

This only requires one run of `pdflatex` and no extra applications. This produces:

[image: image of list of abbreviations]

Comment: Thanks man. But as I mentioned in the question, I don't want to cross reference the _acronyms_. I don't want `\gls{ny} and \gls{la} are in \gls{us}.` but just the text and the list of acronyms. If I do the way you mentioned, it shows both the complete form and acronyms short form _New York (NY)._ I just need _NY_ in the main text and the complete description in the output acronyms list. @Nicola Talbot

Comment: @ArslanYousaf In the second example, change `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}` to `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}`.

Comment: Please compile the above mentioned code. It does not generate any acronym list for me. Sometimes LaTex is just a pain for me!

Comment: `Short` or `long-short` comes after. But I didn't even get at-least an acronyms list.

Comment: @ArslanYousaf Did you run `makeglossaries`? You can add `automake` to the package options to do this automatically.