# Why my code is not printing the glossary made with glossaries package

Tags: glossaries

I'm trying to create a glossary using the `glossaries` package at the end of my document, however, even I copying examples, the document is not showing the glossary. What is wrong with my code, or what I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{latex}%
{%
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}%
{%
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\gls{latex} and \gls{maths}\par
%
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EXTRA QUESTION:** What is the difference between `\makeglossary` and `\makeglossaries`, and `\printglossary` and `\printglossaries`

Comment: @Schweinebacke `makeglossaries` program? No, I have not run this program. Is it avaliable for download somwhere? How can I run it?

Comment: `\makeglossary` is just a synonym for `\makeglossaries`. (The obsolete `glossary` package which `glossaries` replaced used `\makeglossary`, so the name was allowed to make it easier for users transferring from `glossary` to `glossaries`. The new name `\makeglossaries` emphasizes that `glossaries` can have multiple glossaries.) `\makeglossary` isn't documented in the `glossaries` manual so it's best to stick with `\makeglossaries` as modifications to `\makeglossaries` may not be reflected in `\makeglossary`.

Comment: The `makeglossaries` program is provided with the `glossaries` package. You need to add it to your build process.

Comment: Windows users may have to install perl to use the `makeglossaries` script.

Comment: There's also a Lua alternative `makeglossaries-lite` that doesn't require Perl. It doesn't have all the features of `makeglossaries` but it's fine for documents that just use `makeindex`. What are you using to build your document? If it's TeXWorks you could try the question [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/)

Comment: The difference between `\printglossary` and `\printglossaries` is that `\printglossary` only displays a single glossary (and has an optional argument to change the defaults) whereas `\printglossaries` does `\printglossary` for each defined glossary.